# GRUB boot loader(Ubuntu) not working after updating

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, bootloader

I have a system with ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64 installed. It has stopped booting up after updating. As I power on it, screen glows for 1 sec and it shuts down. I have tried to open GRUB boot loader by pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key while booting but nothing happened, screen just glows for a second and goes off. This happens sometimes, most of time as I power on the wifi symbol gets on and laptop shuts down.The screen doesn't glow in this at all. I downloaded the Ubuntu from net and installed with the help of bootable USB on laptop.It's been 2 days and I have a lot of data in the laptop.

Any Solutions/Suggestions ? Thanks In advance.

Comment: This might be a power problem ... if this is a laptop try removing the battery and AC power for 2-3 minutes, then connect AC [no battery] and try to reboot. Post back with outcome.

Comment: @pfeiffep It started ,don't know how.
but will try this next time for sure if this happens.But still there are grub boot loader problems.
can u help me in that 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/772771/gpt-guid-partition-table-detected-on-dev-sda-the-util-fdisk-doesnt-suppor

Thanks

Comment: there are replies in that thread that are worthy ... let's not mixed these 2 threades

Comment: @pfeiffep it happened again , i did your's mention things and it worked.
But everytime I shut down laptop for few hours it doesn't start and I have to remove battery and do this.
Is there any solution to it ?or How can I repair it? are there any issues with my **Ubuntu**.?
any solutions?

Comment: If your laptop will boot using AC power ONLY and the problem doesn't appear perhaps there's a battery or charging problem. If the problem(s) are in the power system there's absolutely no way to determine the viability of the software intallation.

Answer (score 0):

boot live ubuntu from a stick and try running boot-repair
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

i have used this a few times after i messed up grub by installing windows.
try a repair and reboot after. ive had instances where the second time i ran boot-repair it fixed the problem

Comment: It started ,don't know how and I did some grub checking and I have asked question again .
Can u help me there.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/772771/gpt-guid-partition-table-detected-on-dev-sda-the-util-fdisk-doesnt-suppor

Thanks

Comment: I strongly suggest fixing one problem at a time, or at least in this case boot your laptop with the battery removed to proceed.